# Make Wordpress PRIVATE posts sticky

Tags: wordpress

I have created a new role and allowed that role to view private posts. Essentially I now have a "members" area that can view private posts. The problem is that I can't find a way to make posts both private and sticky.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Wordpress won't allow a post to be both private and sticky; however, I was able to find a solution.

I marked it as private. I added code in my plugin that uses `stick_post()` to use a custom defined number of posts a sticky. Wordpress takes the sticky tag off on update because it is private but the `stick_post()` code just puts it back on.